# PySimpleGui - is there a way to empty the screen?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am making a quiz app, when all the questions have been answered I want a completed text to appear without any input fields or text from previous state. I'm thinking of using an invisible tab which the user cannot click on until the questions have been answered or clearing all the text and making the new text appear at the end. Is there a better way than both of these? If not, which one is better?

[gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXWvB.png)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import json

data = {
    "question": [
        "Q1. What equation for force",
        "Q2. Define isotope",
        "Q3. Define wavelength",
        "Q4. Define modal dispersion"
    ],
    "answers": [

        "f=ma",
        "isotopes are atoms of the same element but with a different number of neutrons",
        "the least distance between adjacent particles which are in phase",
        "causes light travelling at different angles to arrive at different times"

    ],
    "automark": [
        ["F=ma", "f=ma", "F=MA"],
        ["same number of protons", "different number of neutrons", "same element"],
        ["minimum distance between adjacent particles", "particles which are in phase"],
        ["different angles", "different times"]
    ],
    "mastery": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "incorrect": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}


def nextset(no, no2, do_not_stop, list1, list2):
    endlist = []  # number in the list represent question number
    while not do_not_stop:
        if no == 3:
            do_not_stop = True

        if list2[no] == list1[no2]:
            position = list1.index(list2[no])
            no += 1
            no2 = 0
            endlist.append(position)
            print(endlist)

        else:
            no2 += 1
    savetoexternal(endlist)


def savetoexternal(endlist):
    with open("savefile.json", 'w') as f:  # creates external json file to be read from later
        json.dump(endlist, f, indent=2)


# main program
def listdata(list1):
    do_not_stop = False
    no = 0
    no2 = 0
    list2 = list1.copy()
    list2.sort(
        reverse=True)  # ordered question from highest to lowest while keeping original intact to preserve question number
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
    nextset(no, no2, do_not_stop, list1, list2)


def main():
    # initialise the question, question number and answer
    question = data['question']
    answers = data['answers']
    automark = data['automark']
    mastery = data['mastery']
    incorrect = data['incorrect']
    q_no = 0
    max_q_no = 4

    sg.theme('DarkBlack')  # Adding colour
    # Stuff in side the window

    layout = [[sg.Text("                      "), sg.Text(question[0], key='_Q1_', visible=True),
               sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Text("correct answer:"), sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUTA-')],
              [sg.Text("automark allows:"), sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUTB-')],
              [sg.Text("your answer was:"), sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUTC-')],
              [sg.Text('Answer here:   '), sg.InputText(size=(60, 1), key='-INPUT-', do_not_clear=False)],
              [sg.Button('Submit', key='b1'), sg.Button('Cancel'), sg.Button('Skip')]]

    # Create the Window
    window = sg.Window('Quiz', layout, size=(655, 565))
    # Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
            break
        window['_Q1_'].Update(visible=False)
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(question[q_no])
        select_not_mastered_question = True

        if all(x == 3 for x in mastery):
            print("all questions mastered")  # add to gui later
            list1 = []
            q_no = 0
            while q_no < max_q_no:
                list1.append(incorrect[q_no])
                q_no += 1
            q_no = 0
            listdata(list1)

        if values['-INPUT-'] == answers[q_no]:  # list index out of range occurs when all questions are complete, need to add completed screen by using else statement
            mastery[q_no] += 1  # need to add to gui
            print(mastery)
            q_no += 1
            if q_no == max_q_no:
                q_no = 0

            while select_not_mastered_question:  # make sures the next question has not already been mastered
                if mastery[q_no] == 3:
                    if q_no == max_q_no:
                        q_no = 0
                    q_no += 1
                else:
                    select_not_mastered_question = False

            print("current q_no:", q_no)

            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(question[q_no])  # accepts the answer as correct and moves onto the next question
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('')

        if values['-INPUT-'] in automark[q_no]:  # shows the answer was correct but missing some key points
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update(answers[q_no])
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update(automark[q_no])
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('partially correct')

        if event == 'Skip':
            q_no += 1
            if q_no == max_q_no:
                q_no = 0

            while select_not_mastered_question:  # make sures the next question has not already been mastered
                if mastery[q_no] == 3:
                    if q_no == max_q_no:
                        q_no = 0
                    q_no += 1
                else:
                    select_not_mastered_question = False

            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(question[q_no])  # moves onto the next question
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('')
            window['-INPUT-'].update(disabled=False)
            window['b1'].update(disabled=False)

        elif values['-INPUT-'] == '':
            print('answer was:', answers[q_no])  # for testing
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update(
                answers[q_no])  # shows that the answer is incorrect and displays the right answer
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update(automark[q_no])
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('incorrect')
            window['-INPUT-'].update(disabled=True)
            window['b1'].update(disabled=True)
            incorrect[q_no] += 1
            if mastery[q_no] == 0:
                print(mastery)
            else:
                mastery[q_no] -= 1
                print(mastery)

    window.close()


main()
```

Comment: Hello Rick! What have you tried so far? Could you please update you post, providing actual code? It will help people understanding your specific situation and finding an appropriate solution for you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NickS1 added code. There's an index error btw (I'm working on it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I set two frames and only frame visible at the same time.

User code is so long, so use my code to demo how it go here.
Remember to upgrade PySimpleGUI, maybe from github.

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def new_questions(number):
 return [(f'{i}x{j} = ?', f'{i*j}')
    for i, j in [(randint(1, 9), randint(1, 9)) for i in range(number)]]

font = ("Courier New", 16)
sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=font)

number = 5

frame1 = [
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Text("", key='Result')],
    [sg.Text("Ready to answer questions")],
    [sg.Button("Start"), sg.Button("Exit")],
    [sg.VPush()],
]

frame2 = [
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Text("Question:"), sg.Text("",  size=7, key="Question")],
    [sg.Text("Answer:"),   sg.Input("", size=7, key="Answer")],
    [sg.Button("OK")],
    [sg.VPush()],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Frame("", frame1, size=(360, 200), visible=True,  key='Frame1',  element_justification='center'),
     sg.Frame("", frame2, size=(360, 200), visible=False, key='Frame2',  element_justification='center')],
]

window = sg.Window("Test", layout, finalize=True)
question, answer, result = window['Question'], window['Answer'], window['Result']
frame1, frame2 = window['Frame1'], window['Frame2']
answer.bind("<Return>", "-Return")
sg.theme("DarkGrey")

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Start':
        frame2.update(visible=True)
        frame1.update(visible=False)
        index, correct = 0, 0
        questions = new_questions(number)
        q, a = questions[index]
        question.update(q)
        answer.update('')
        answer.set_focus()
    elif event in ('OK', "Answer-Return") and index < number:
        ans = values['Answer'].strip()
        index += 1
        if ans == a:
            correct += 1
            sg.popup(f"Your answer is correct ({correct}/{index})")
        else:
            sg.popup(f"Correct answer is {a} ({correct}/{index})")
        if index < number:
            q, a = questions[index]
            question.update(q)
            answer.update('')
            answer.set_focus()
        else:
            frame1.update(visible=True)
            frame2.update(visible=False)
            result.update(f"{correct}/{index} correct !!")

window.close()
```

Comment: tysm. Could you explain what answer.set_focus() does and why it is used here

Comment: It maybe lost the focus on the input element `window['Answer']` when switching between windows or frames, `answer.set_focus()` used here to set focus to input element, so you don't need to click on the input element before starting your input.